# How to remove empty line in Jinja (exporting from readwise to logseq)

Tags: jinja2

I am trying to export highlights from readwise to logseq with correct page properties.

However for some pages an empty line appears which prevents all properties to appear correctly.
How can I fix this?

This is the current jinja code:

```
author:: [[{{author}}]]\
full-title:: "{{full_title}}"\
category:: #{{category}}\
if url %}url:: {{url}}{% endif %}\
if document_note       %}document_note:: {{document_note}}{% endif %}\
if document_tags %}tags:: {% for tag in document_tags %}#[[{{tag}}]] {% endfor %} {% endif %}
if image_url %}![]({{image_url}}){% endif %}`
```

ine issue for example: If document note is empty it still creates a line for that property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it:

```
author:: [[{{author}}]]\
full-title:: "{{full_title}}"\
category:: #{{category}}\
{% if url %}url:: {{url}}{% endif -%}\
{% if document_note %}document_note:: {{document_note}}{% endif -%}
{% if document_tags %}tags:: {% for tag in document_tags %}#[[{{tag}}]] {% endfor %} {% endif %}\
{% if image_url %}![]({{image_url}}){% endif %}
```

Changes include adding - before the % in the endif